# Showing transitivity of a relation for a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I have to check if the following set is an equivalence relation:

> Set: $A=\mathbb{R}$
> Relation: $x \sim y$ if $x=ay$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Q}\backslash \{0\}$

I know I have to use the reflexive, symmetric and transitive properties here.

It's reflexive since for $x \sim x$, we have $x=ax$ which is true if $a=1$.
It's symmetric because for all $x,y \in A$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have: $x=ay$, $y=bx$which implies that $y=(ba)y$. Since $0$ is not included in $\mathbb{Q}$, this is always possible since we will never have a division by $0$ error or some kind of statement which does not make sense.

How do I show transitivity though?

I believe this means I have to show that if $x=ay$ and $y=bz$ then $x=cz$ for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Is my understanding right? How would I proceed from here?

Comment: The `set-theory` and `elementary-set-theory` tags are almost never *both* appropriate. Please read the descriptions of the tags to see which one is appropriate for your post.

Comment: Your symmetry argument makes no sense. What you need to do is show that if $x\sim y$, then $y\sim x$. You seem to be trying to argue that if $x\sim y$ and $y\sim x$ then something or other happens, which is not what you need to do. For transitivity, show tiat if $x=ay$ and $y=bz$, then there must exist a $c\neq 0$ such that $x=cz$. You need to *produce* the $c$, not assume one exists.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Basically for symmetry, I also have to likewise PRODUCE the b from what I am understanding right? I can't assume it's true and use it t prove something else and say that symmetry holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You need only to use existence quantifier: if $\exists a, x=ay$ and $\exists b,y=bz$, then $\exists c = a\cdot b$ for which $x=ab \cdot z=c\cdot z$.

For symmetry: if $\exists a, x=ay,a\ne 0$, then $y = \frac{1}{a}x$.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I basically went $x=cz$. I know $x=ay$ and $y=bz$, so if I substitute everything into $x=cz$, I get $a(bz)=cz$ or $abz=cz$ which implies that $ab=c$ so transitivity works. Is that the right idea?

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for all $s,t\in\Bbb R$, we define  $s\sim t$ as $\exists a\in\Bbb Q{\smallsetminus}\{0\}~(s=at)$.   So obviously we will be looking to affirm the existence of such a *non-zero rational factor* relating real terms.

Reflexivity: $\checkmark$

- The multiplicative identity is a non-zero rational number. That is $1\in\Bbb Q{\smallsetminus}\{0\}$.
- So for any $x\in\Bbb R$ we have $x=1x$.
- Therefore $\forall x\in \Bbb R~.(x\sim x)$

Symmetry:  $\checkmark$

- When $a\in\Bbb Q{\smallsetminus}\{0\}$ then its multiplicative inverse, $a^{-1}$, is also an non-zero-rational number. That is: $a^{-1}\in\Bbb Q{\smallsetminus}\{0\}$.
- Thus for any $x,y\in\Bbb R$ and such $a$, where $x=ay$, then we have $y=a^{-1}x$.
- Therefore: $\forall x\in\Bbb R~\forall y\in\Bbb R~.(x\sim y\to y\sim x).$

Transitivity:  $\checkmark$

- For any $a,b\in\Bbb Q{\smallsetminus}\{0\}$ then their product is also a non-zero rational. That is: $ab\in\Bbb Q{\smallsetminus}\{0\}$.
- Thus for any $x,y,z\in\Bbb R$ and such $a,b$, where $x=ay$ and $y=bz$, then we have $x=ab\,z$.
- Therefore $\forall x\in\Bbb R~\forall y\in\Bbb R~\forall z\in\Bbb R~.((x\sim y\land y\sim z)\to x\sim z).$